# Standard error, standard deviation and error propagation

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, uncertainty, error-propagation

I measured a quantity 100 times to get 100 measurements denoted as $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_{100}$, with uncertainties as $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_{100}$. Now if I want to report the average of these 100 measurements, how should I report the uncertainty of this average value? I'm particularly confused as several ways seem reasonable to me.

- Method A: Report the sample standard deviation, namely, $\sigma_x=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2}{n-1}}$, where $n$ is 100 since we have 100 measurements.
- Method B: Report the standard error of the mean, namely, $s=\sigma / \sqrt{n}$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the distribution where the measurements were taken from. To my understanding, $\sigma$ here should be the population standard deviation, which is unknown in this case and should be estimated by the sample standard deviation, $\sigma_x$. That is, the reported uncertainty should be $s\approx \sigma_x/\sqrt{n}=\sigma_x=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i}(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2}{n(n-1)}}$
- Method C: Perform error propagation, namely, $\frac{1}{100}\sqrt{e_{1}^2 + e_{2}^2 + ... + e_{100}^2}$.

Which method is correct? Or actually, none of them is correct?

Comment: How *exactly* are you estimating the "uncertainties" $e1, e2, \ldots$? If any method other than residual $e_i = x_i - \bar{x}$, such as in a time series analysis, then none of these methods make sense. And if in fact $e_i = x_i - \bar{x}$, it should be trivial to show 1 and 3 are basically the same once your formulae are corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. To my understanding, $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_{100}$ were estimated by a complicated bootstrapping protocol associated with the estimator that I was using. If none of the methods above is correct, could you possibly point out how the uncertainty of the reported value should be calculated?

Comment: Knowing little else, it would be reasonable to assume the bootstrap was applied because standard normal theory wasn't appropriate for the problem at hand, thus method A and B are off. The real question is why you only have 100 bootstrap replications when 10 or 100 times that would be recommended. Calculating uncertainty from bootstrap samples is discussed elsewhere on this site. It's not trivial.

Comment: I guess what confuses me a little now is why the method for calculating $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_{100}$ is relevant to how the uncertainty of the reported value should be calculated. Should it be as simple as performing error propagation?